# after seven refresh react no longer loads data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have encountered this problem and don't know how to solve it:

I have a page in react that makes a call to the backend made in express js which in turn makes an API call to a microservice to fetch the data, everything works but I noticed that when reloading the page seven times it crashes and doesn't load them for me, however react, express server and the microservice don't give me any errors. What can I do to fix it?

react page:

```
export default function Dashboard(){
    

    const [houses, setHouses] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState();
    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log("id" , id);
    console.log(Cookies.get('cookie'))
    
    function refreshPage() {
        window.location.reload(false);
      }

    useEffect(()=>{
        // const utente = localStorage.getItem('idUtente');
        const utente = Cookies.get('idUtente')
        console.log("utente: ", utente)
        setLoading(true);
        
        fetch(`/api/getInfoHouses/${utente}/${id}`,{
            method:'GET',
            credentials:"include",
            // mode:'no-cors',
            header:{    
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                
            }
            
        }).then((risposta) => {
            if(risposta.ok){
                return risposta.json();
            }
            
        }).then((dati) => {
            console.log(dati.body)
            const message = dati.body.message
            

            if(message == undefined){
                const house = dati.body;
                setHouses(house);
                setLoading(false)
            }else{
                setError(message);
                setLoading(false)
                
            }

        })
      
    },[])

    if(loading){
        return < DashboardLoading mappa={mappa}/>
    }

    if(error != '' && error != undefined){
        return(
            <>
                <Banner message={error}></Banner>
            </>
        )
    }else{
        return(
        
            <div className="hero">
    
                <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                
                
    
                
                
                    
                        <h3 className="sottotitolo">Abitazioni del gruppo residenziale</h3>
                        <div className="slider"> 
                        {houses.map(house => (    
                            <div key={house.id_casa} className="card">
                                
                                <div className="infoHouse">
                                     <div className="id-abitazione">
                                        <p>ID Abitazione: </p> 
                                        <p>{house.id_casa}</p>
                                    </div>
                                <div className="nome-abitazione">
                                    <p>Nome Abitazione: </p>
                                    <p>{house.arduino}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="indirizzo-abitazione">
                                    <p>Indirizzo: </p>
                                    <p>{house.indirizzo}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="carico-abitazione">
                                    <p>Carico: </p>
                                    <p>{house.nome_carico}</p>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form">
                                    <form method="POST" action="https://mydomain/api/deletecard">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id_casa" value={house.id_casa}></input>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="nome_quartiere" value={house.nome_quartiere}></input>
                                        <button type="submit" onClick={refreshPage}><img src={deleteButton}></img> </button>
                                        {/* <button type="submit"><img src={deleteButton}></img> </button> */}
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="container-img">    
                                <img src={mappa} alt="mappa di distribuzione"></img>
    
    
                                <div className="circle">
                                    <span className=""></span>  
                                    <p>{house.pannello}</p>
                                </div>  
    
                                <div className="circle2">
                                    <span className=""></span>  
                                    <p>{house.caricoabitazione}</p>    
                                </div>  
    
                                <div className="circle3">
                                    <span className=""></span> 
                                    <p>{house.enel}</p>     
                                </div>  
    
                                <div className="circle4">
                                    <span className=""></span>  
                                    <p>{house.caricocomplesso}</p>    
                                </div>  
    
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    
            ))}
            

     
            </div>  
                
                
                   
                
    
            </div>
        )
    }
```

express server api:

```
app.get('/getInfoHouses/:utente/:id',cors(), async function(req, res){
    console.log("in get info")
    const utente = req.params.utente;
    const id = req.params.id;
    const response = await fetch('http://archiver:3002/v1/api/case-quartiere',{
        method:'POST',
        header:{
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        },
        body:new URLSearchParams({
            token: userLog.get(utente),
            nome_quartiere: id,
            username: utente
        }),

        mode: 'no-cors',
        
    }).then((res) => {console.log(res);return res.json()});
    console.log("la risposta: ");
    console.log(response)
    if(response === "error"){
        return res.send({
            body: response
        }).status(400)
    }else{
        return res.send({
            body: response.data
        }).status(200)
    }
})
```

microservice api:

```
const getHouses = async (token, nome_quartiere, username) => {
    let houses;
    const querySQL = "my query";
    try{
        // const payload = await verifier.verify(token);
        // console.log("Token valido, Payload: ", payload);
        const user = username;
        const nomeQuartiere = nome_quartiere;
        pool.connect();
        const data = await pool.query(querySQL, [user, nomeQuartiere]);
        houses = data.rows;
        return houses;
    }catch (err){
        console.log("Token false ", err);
        // res.status(400).send("error")
    } 
}
```

I use the pg pool, he should close the connections
Database config file:

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config()

const pool = new Pool({
    user:process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
    password:process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    host:process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    port:process.env.RDS_PORT,
    database:process.env.RDS_DBNAME
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: i'm curious how do you make refresh. By click button or keyboard refresh ? can you try `<button type="button" onClick={refreshPage}><img src={deleteButton}></img> </button>` I think your issue is more frontend related errors

Comment: What is the error you are getting when it crashes. could you please let us know the exact exception you are getting? You can get this on console.

Comment: @502_Geek refresh by keyboard

Comment: @vishal the only error I get in the browser console is this : "Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received"

Comment: how's your db config file? Does connection require to release after execute your query ?

Comment: I think this is not your code error, do not refresh for 7 times, just wait for some time and see the console, it should come after some time. Try to use incognito tab as extensions as by default inactive. have a look https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/issues/384.

Comment: @502_Geek I updated the problem with the server configuration file

Comment: @vishal I waited a while, and another error that the browser console shows me is this "WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:3000/ws' failed: " but I don't think it's this